# Alignment issue with parent relative / child absolute when element types added to child vary

Tags: html, css

I fell into some kind of CSS pitfall I can't explain myself.

http://jsfiddle.net/z2mf21ry/

Having a position:relative parent with overflow hidden, I have added a container with position:absolute and right:0. The container is properly centered on the right of its parent, when I add div.element elements in it. If I add more divs, the container gets wider (since I don't want elements to be wrapped into a new line) and at some time I can only see the last n divs (case#1).

Then, I replaced the first div by a 1-row 2-cell table with long text in cells, and that's still fine (case#2).

Finally, I have removed the text of one cell (or set only one character) such as:

```
<div class="element">
  <table><tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="received">Child 1 with table c1</td>
      <td class="received">a</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody></table>
</div>
```

At this point, the right centering disappeared (case#3) as if the middle of the container was aligned with the middle of the parent. Moreover, a scrollbar appeared.

I have the same behavior with Firefox 44, IE 9, Chrome 48.
I guess it must be a misunderstanding of CSS flow, but I don't understand why and I don't know how I could track this kind of issue.

If you can check it out and tell me how you highlight the issue (for example, starting firebug, highlight such element, look at Layout etc.) it'll great.
Thanks!

---

EDIT: It seems to be fine if the no-wrap elements added to the child container have display:table-cell (case#4). Here is another jsfiddle removing the parent overflow:hidden and adding a margin to see what's going on when the green box seems not centered properly on the right in case#3. In fact, it seems that elements are out the container flow.

http://jsfiddle.net/yfny908g/

Also, the problem in case#3 may be solved using min-width instead of width: 25px in td elements.

It still doesn't explain the difference between case#2 and case#3.

Comment: I don't understand what your desired result is.

Comment: Hi Chris, I just wonder why case#3 is different from case#2 (ie. why 'Child 3' is not aligned to the right of green box and why a scrollbar appears whereas it is not present in case#2 even with a longer text)

Comment: This markup is a bit weird. The light-green box is a table but not all content and cells are visible. Is this intentional? You're also using properties such as `position: absolute` and `white-space: nowrap` and I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, the parent overflow is hidden. As I said, the purpose here is probably to dig and understand CSS flow internals.

Comment: I don't think I can help you because you're using properties that don't seem to make much sense in the context of your application. Maybe if you narrow the example down to only use elements and properties that you actually *need* to demonstrate your question. Also, no need to show case1 or 2. Do that and I might be able to assist. Right now this is too confusing.